# Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have an issue with MySQL. When I'm trying to start it, that gives me an error message, which is

```
2015-12-10 10:52:31 13f4 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 16.0M
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1902092 and 1902092 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1902102 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2015-12-10 10:52:31 5108 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2015-12-10 10:52:32 5108 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.26-74.0 started; log sequence number 1902102
2015-12-10 10:52:32 1760 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) not yet started
2015-12-10 10:52:32 5108 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2015-12-10 10:52:32 5108 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2015-12-10 10:52:32 5108 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2015-12-10 10:52:32 5108 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2015-12-10 10:52:32 5108 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

I changed to InnoDB yesterday, but no problems were found. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of mysql (or percona)?  Was this an upgrade?  Or a fresh install?  If upgrade, what was the previous version?

Comment: I just installed XAMPP with PHP 5.6.15 and MariaDB 10.0.17.

Comment: I'm having trouble with selinux. `journalctl -b -t setroubleshoot` seems helpful for troubleshooting

Answer (score 91):

These instructions worked for me in a fresh install of MariaDB in Arch Linux:

```sh
systemctl stop mariadb
rm -R /var/lib/mysql/*
mysql_install_db --user=mysql --basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
systemctl start mariadb
```

Comment: FYI these have to be run with elevated privileges

Comment: Please note that `rm -R /var/lib/mysql/*` will delete ALL database data.

Comment: And what if you already have some databases in `/var/lib/mysql` which is the default places for them ? These instructions just erase all databases !

Comment: If the problem remains, the configuration in /etc/mysql or /etc/mysql/conf.d may be incorrect. I encountered the issue after using an invalid encryption key file (loose_file_key_management_filename), for example.

Answer (score 79):

removing (renaming) this files in /var/lib/mysql:

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
aria_log_control
```

and restarting:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

solved it for me

Comment: This worked in XAMPP windows.

Comment: also works for windows setup with xampp. Just got to xampp->mysql->data  and locate and delete these files. Now restart xampp services and it should work fine. I had following error in mysql setup with xampp 3.2  `2021-12-27 16:13:20 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2021-12-27 16:13:20 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize plugins.
2021-12-27 16:13:20 0 [ERROR] Aborting`

Comment: This worked for me as well but can someone explain why this prevents the server from starting up properly?

Comment: On windows it is xampp\mysql\data

Answer (score 36):

### Simple solution:

There is a `backup` folder in the `..\Xampp\mysql` directory. Copy its contents and paste in  `..\Xampp\mysql\data`. Then the error will be gone.

Comment: This works, wish I knew why :)

Answer (score 15):

For the xampp users, you just need to replace following files from Xampp/mysql/backup folder to Xampp/mysql/data folder (FYI: Keep a backup copy of data folder before actioning just to be on a safer side..)

[image]

Answer (score 12):

For windows / xampp,

1. Stop mysql service
2. Go to mysql/data directory
3. Please take the backup of highlighted file in separate place and then delete it from data directory.

[image]

4. Start Mysql service.

The above method solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 4):

For Windows this worked for me Perfectly:

Close your xammp completely using Task Manager

removing these files in /xampp/mysql:

```
ib_logfile0
ib_logfile1
aria_log_control
aria_log.* ( * == some Number)
```

Start again your xampp.

Answer (score 1):

Just renamed these files and the issue fixed. After rename files next restart of mysql it will automatically create new files so no need to copy files from backup folder.
[image]

Comment: No need to worry about data loss

Answer (score 0):

I had this same FEEDBACK/plugins error using MariaDB 10.4 in Docker.  Switching to MariaDB 10.3 solved it.

Comment: This does not explain why switching to 10.3 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

From me it was `/usr/bin/mariadbd` process stock into the memory I was only manage to stop it with

```
sudo killall mariadbd
```

Answer (score 0):

For my Windows XAMPP install, copying the files from the backup directory did clear the mysql error.  However, it also reset my Wordpress install.  I suspect that the underlying issue was a database corruption issue caused by the "bleeding edge" install of Wordpress on my local PC.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
mv /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control /var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control.orig
```

this worked for me

from
https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/12377243101591-MariaDB-fails-to-start-Aria-engine-is-not-enabled-or-did-not-start

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34713025)

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too, I tried some solution that you told before but doesn't work.
I tried replace one by one the tables/files in data/mysql with the new one (I got it from backup) and.. the problem solved when I replace db.* files.

So my MariaDb running again after I replace files db.frm, db.MAD, and db.MAI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34938140)

Comment: Seems like a sensible suggestion. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion by Mohit Verma works ...

For windows / xampp,

Stop mysql service
Go to mysql/data directory
Please take the backup of highlighted file in separate place and then delete it from data directory.
[image]
![][1]

Start Mysql service.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. But I have to do it on every start up. Does anybody have a permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error shown but I found a different solution. I found that my backup had a mysql database and my current data didn't have that. I placed back the mysql database and my database worked just fine again.

Answer (score 0):

So... in my particular case i had a quite old installation (10.3.31) of MariaDB on my Raspberry PI. One day, my system collapsed and I couldn't boot it up anymore so I had to make a copy of files from the SD card and move them to my new server instance. Even though my setup was very similar and I was getting the same exact error, I couldn't resolve it by applying the solutions proposed here.

What helped was:

1. Installing the exact same version of MariaDB from the manufacturer site.
2. Replacing all the contents of `data` dir with the old
   contents from the old machine.
3. running MariaDB in safe mode using `mysqld_safe` from the `bin` dir.

If your database files sit in another directory you might want to use the
`--datadir` parameter like so:

```
# mysqld_safe --datadir=/var/lib/mysql/
```

Finally, from there I was able to dump the files to a `.sql` dump.

```
# mysqldump database -u root -p > dump.sql
```