# Error in xampp 3.2.4 in mysql server. It shows "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly"

Tags: mysql, xampp

Yesterday, everything was working good. But today after started my xampp server it shows "Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.". I already checked error logs for this error. I found :

```
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1,    chunk size = 16M
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB.    Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'D:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 304802; transaction id  201
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from D:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [ERROR] Could not open mysql.plugin table. Some plugins may be not loaded
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [ERROR] Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.servers' doesn't exist
2020-04-02 15:37:47 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I don't understand why this happening. Can anyone help me to get rid of this error?

Comment: Maybe check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34198735/could-not-open-mysql-plugin-table-some-plugins-may-be-not-loaded/46147066

Comment: @Tum Solved. I have Uninstalled existing Xampp and install again. But lost database tables :(

Comment: @AnthonyShoshiGomes please add your solution to this post.